# Pipe awk's results to sed (deletion)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am using an awk command (someawkcommand) that prints these lines (awkoutput):

```
>Genome1
ATGCAAAAG
CAATAA
```

and then, I want to use this output (awkoutput) as the input of a sed command. Something like that:

```
someawkcommand | sed 's/awkoutput//g' file1.txt > results.txt
```

file1.txt:

```
>Genome1
ATGCAAAAG
CAATAA
>Genome2
ATGAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
CAA
>Genome3
ACCC
```

The final objective is to delete all lines in a file (`file1.txt`) containing the exact pattern found previously by awk.

The file `results.txt` contains (output of sed):

```
>Genome2
ATGAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
CAA
>Genome3
ACCC
```

How should I write the sed command? Is there any simple way that sed will recognize the output of awk as its input?

Comment: IT's unclear for me. Did you want to delete some lines in an awk output through sed based on a pattern?

Comment: I want to delete all lines matching the awk ouput in file1.txt using sed. I hope this helps..

Comment: Maybe you could 1) delete those lines with `awk` itself, or 2) use `grep` with `-v` (exclude lines matching given pattern) option?

Comment: You should change the awk command in a way that it produces the correct results. No sed needed here.

Comment: I know there are many ways to obtain the same result but here I was asking how to achieve it using sed. Anyway, I will try to modify the awk command.

Comment: @CaTh: `sed` doesn't allow `s///;` commands to match a pattern which spans several lines, so I don't see how you expect that to work. I didn't understand your comment that the file is too big to save the awk output. Are you saying that `awkoutput` itself is too big to store in memory???

Comment: sed is always the wrong tool when you are doing anything that spans lines. It's language constructs to support those kinds of operations became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: @rici: By my comment, I mean that I need to do multiple awk per file and so the file containing all the 'awkoutput' will take too much memory.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have no doubt awk is very powerful but I don't fully understand how it works yet. From what I learned in the past, I tough sed could be a good tool to erase lines (by replacing something by nothing).

Comment: @CaTh: So you're planning on deleting a huge number of stanzas? Perhaps you need to step back and rethink your approach. Regardless, your problem description is obviously not clear enough to get a good solution here.

Comment: @CaTh it's not about power it's about simplicity and clarity. sed can do just about anything awk can, but if it's for anything spanning multiple lines the resulting sed code will be a horrendous mess of hieroglyphics that needs to be completely re-written for the slightest requirements change while the awk code will be clear, simple, easy to enhance and in many cases briefer. If you are doing a simple substitution on 1 line, sed is the right tool - otherwise use awk. See the posted sed solutions for examples :-)!

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file1
>Genome1
ATGCAAAAG
CAATAA

$ cat file2
>Genome1
ATGCAAAAG
CAATAA
>Genome2
ATGAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
CAA
>Genome3
ACCC

$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= 'NR==FNR{rmv=$0;next} {sub(rmv,"")} 1' file1 file2
>Genome2
ATGAAAAA
AAAAAAAA
CAA
>Genome3
ACCC
```

The stuff that might be non-obvious to newcomers but are very common awk idioms:

1. `-v RS='^$'` tells awk to read the whole file as one string (instead of it's default one line at a time).
2. `-v ORS=` sets the Output Record Separator to the null string (instead of it's default newline) so that when the file is printed as a string awk doesn't add a newline after it.
3. `NR==FNR` is a condition that is only true for the first input file.
4. `1` is a true condition invoking the default action of printing the current record.

Comment: it works perfect, can you please explain `-v ORS=` and `1` at the end of the command action?  why is it different from `BEGIN{NR="^$"; ORS=""}`

Comment: I added some explanations to my answer. It is not different from `BEGIN{RS="^$"; ORS=""}`, just a different syntax for the same functionality.

Comment: it should be `RS="^$"` rather than `NR="^$"` in my question:) Thanks for your explanation, really helps.  +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible `sed` solution:

```
someawkcommand | sed -n 's_.*_/&/d;_;H;${x;s_\n__g p}' | sed -f - file1.txt
```

First `sed` command turns output from `someawkcommand` into a `sed` expression.

Concretely, it turns

```
>Genome1
ATGCAAAAG
CAATAA
```

into:

```
/>Genome1/d;/ATGCAAAAG/d;/CAATAA/d;
```

(in `sed` language: delete lines containing those patterns; mind that you will have to escape `/`,`[`,`]`,`*`,`^`,`$` in your `awk` output if there are some, with another substitution for instance).

Second `sed` command reads it as input expression (`-f -` reads `sed` commands from file `-`, i.e. gets it from pipe) and applies to file `file1.txt`.

**Remark for other readers:**
OP wants to use `sed`, but as notified in comments, it may not be the easiest way to solve this question. Deleting lines with `awk` could be simpler. Another (easy) solution could be to use `grep` with `-v` (invert match) and `-f` (read patterns from files) options, in this way:

```
someawkcommand | grep -v -f - file1.txt
```

---

**Edit:** Following @rici's comments, here is a new command that takes output from `awk` as a single multiline pattern.

**Disclaimer:** It gets dirty. Kids, *don't* do it home. Grown-ups are strongly encouraged to consider avoiding `sed` for that.

```
someawkcommand | \
    sed -n 'H;${x;s_\n__;s_\n_\\n_g;s_.*_H;${x;s/\\n//;s/&//g p}_ p}' | \
    sed -n -f - file1.txt
```

Output from inner `sed` is:

```
H;${x;s/\n//;s/>Genome1\nATGCAAAAG\nCAATAA//g p}
```

Additional drawback: it will add an empty line instead of removed pattern. Can't fix it easily (problems if pattern is at beginning/end of file). Add a substitution to remove it if you really feel like it.

Comment: That's extremely unlikely to be what OP wants, because `/CAATAA/d;' (for example) will delete *any* line *containing* `CAATAA`. You could use `/^CAATAA$/d` which will at least only delete exact matches, but you'll still delete other lines which happen to match but are not part of a `Genome 1` stanza. Your `grep` solution suffers from the same problems (for the first, see `-x` option; also `-F` to avoid metacharacters).

Comment: @rici You're telling me that output from `awk` should be considered as a single multiline pattern, right? I already thought that `sed` was not a good solution but in fact it's even worse than that! I suppose you're right, but I'd appreciate clarification from OP anyway.

Comment: That's definitely how I read the OP. But clarification would be useful. (The point about matching the whole line applies in either case. Suppose the output were the second stanza, instead of the first. Then a partial match on `CAA` would cause the last line in the Genome 1 stanza to be deleted, which cannot be correct.)

Comment: @rici “fixed” my answer (as far as I can fix it with `sed`).

Answer (score 0):

This is can more easily be done in awk, but the usual "eliminate duplicates" code is not correct. As I understand the question, the goal is to remove entire stanzas from the file.

Here's a possible solution which assumes that the first awk script outputs a single stanza:

```
awk 'NR == FNR       {stanza[nstanza++] = $0; next}
     $0 == stanza[i] {++i; next}
     /^>/ && i == nstanza {i=0; next}
     i               {for (j=0; j<i; ++j) print stanza[j]; i=0}
                     {print $0;}
    ' <(someawkcommand) file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1{h;s/.*/:a;$!{N;ba}/p;d};/^>/!{H;$!d};x;s/\n/\\n/g;s|.*|s/&\\n*//g|p;$s|.*|s/\\n*$//|p;x;h;d' file1
sed -f - file2
```

This builds a script from file1 and then runs it against file2.

The script slurps in file2 and then does a gobal substitution(s) using the contents of file1. Finally it removes  any blank lines at the end file caused by the contents deletion.

To see the script produced from file1, remove the pipe and the second sed command.

An alternative way would be to use diff and sed:

```
 diff -e file2 file1 | sed 's/d/p/g' | sed -nf - file2
```